# Prevent session sharing between browser tabs

Tags: angularjs, spring, cookies, spring-security, spring-session

I have a nasty bug: open two tabs with login pages and log in with different users in each one. All requests from first tab that logged in return with 'unauthorized' error.
Frontend uses SESSION cookie and it looks like that cookie is overwritten by second successful login of the second tab and it tries to use this new cookie when browsing in the first tab.

Using Spring Boot 1.5.8, Spring-session 2, AngularJS 1.7.2
Configuration is very standard, so I don't think these boilerplates would be useful.

Until now I tried to set up a filter on backend that works before authentication, to somehow filter out requests that have known cookie, but I failed at this.

UPD:
Some way of preventing that situation when a user is logged in but with incorrect session is what I seek. Either blocking second login attempt in this browser, or kicking already logged in user when another one logs in in the same broser - all will do.

Comment: That's the normal and expected behavior. If you didn't have that behavior, you would lose your session every time you open a link in a new tab.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff I lean towards preventing that second login from another user.

Comment: If two tabs are opened before login, there is no way to fix that.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff yes, that's the case. But how others work-around this? Some sort of auto-refresh the login page maybe?

Comment: Do you want to log out the first logged in user?

Comment: If that's possible, this would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log out user from other tabs if you set some sort of token on local storage like the code below(in sucessfull login response from server )

```
 localStorage.setItem('logout', 'logout-' + Math.random());
```

and have this function as a run block in your main app module:

```
 function logoutFromOtherTabs(authService, $timeout) {
        'ngInject';

        window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
            if (event.key === 'logout') {
                $timeout(function () {
                    authService.logout();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```